# Getting a topology on StormCrawler to properly write warc files

Tags: java, web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler, apache-storm-topology

The stormcrawler maven archetype seems to not play nice with the warc module in my project. Currently it only creates empty 0 byte files with names like "crawl-20180802121925-00000.warc.gz". Am I missing something here?

I try to enable warc writing by creating a default project like so:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler -DarchetypeArtifactId=storm-crawler-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.10
```

And then adding the dependency to the warc module in the pom.xml like so

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-crawler-warc</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then I add the WARCHdfsBolt to the fetch grouping, while trying to write to a local filesystem directory.

```
public class CrawlTopology extends ConfigurableTopology {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableTopology.start(new CrawlTopology(), args);
    }

    @Override
    protected int run(String[] args) {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

        String[] testURLs = new String[] { "http://www.lequipe.fr/",
                "http://www.lemonde.fr/", "http://www.bbc.co.uk/",
                "http://storm.apache.org/", "http://digitalpebble.com/" };

        builder.setSpout("spout", new MemorySpout(testURLs));

        builder.setBolt("partitioner", new URLPartitionerBolt())
                .shuffleGrouping("spout");

        builder.setBolt("fetch", new FetcherBolt())
                .fieldsGrouping("partitioner", new Fields("key"));

        builder.setBolt("warc", getWarcBolt())
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("fetch");

        builder.setBolt("sitemap", new SiteMapParserBolt())
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("fetch");

        builder.setBolt("feeds", new FeedParserBolt())
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("sitemap");

        builder.setBolt("parse", new JSoupParserBolt())
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("feeds");

        builder.setBolt("index", new StdOutIndexer())
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("parse");

        Fields furl = new Fields("url");

        // can also use MemoryStatusUpdater for simple recursive crawls
        builder.setBolt("status", new StdOutStatusUpdater())
                .fieldsGrouping("fetch", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl)
                .fieldsGrouping("sitemap", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl)
                .fieldsGrouping("feeds", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl)
                .fieldsGrouping("parse", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl)
                .fieldsGrouping("index", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl);

        return submit("crawl", conf, builder);
    }

    private WARCHdfsBolt getWarcBolt() {
        String warcFilePath = "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/warc";

        FileNameFormat fileNameFormat = new WARCFileNameFormat()
                .withPath(warcFilePath);

        Map<String,String> fields = new HashMap<>();
        fields.put("software:", "StormCrawler 1.0 http://stormcrawler.net/");
        fields.put("conformsTo:", "http://www.archive.org/documents/WarcFileFormat-1.0.html");

        WARCHdfsBolt warcbolt = (WARCHdfsBolt) new WARCHdfsBolt()
                .withFileNameFormat(fileNameFormat);
        warcbolt.withHeader(fields);

        // can specify the filesystem - will use the local FS by default
//        String fsURL = "hdfs://localhost:9000";
//        warcbolt.withFsUrl(fsURL);

        // a custom max length can be specified - 1 GB will be used as a default
        FileSizeRotationPolicy rotpol = new FileSizeRotationPolicy(50.0f,
                FileSizeRotationPolicy.Units.MB);
        warcbolt.withRotationPolicy(rotpol);
        return warcbolt;
    }
}
```

Whether I run it locally with or without flux, doesn't seem to make a difference. You can have a look at the demo repo here: https://github.com/keyboardsamurai/storm-test-warc

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking this. In theory content gets written to the WARC files when

1. there is an explicit sync as set in the sync policy [which we have by default at 10 tuples](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/warc/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/warc/WARCHdfsBolt.java#L27)
2. there's an automatic one which happens via tick tuples  [every 15 secs by default](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/1.1.x-branch/external/storm-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/hdfs/bolt/AbstractHdfsBolt.java#L253)
3. the file is rotated - in your case this should happen when the content reaches 50MB

Since the topology you are using as a starting point is not recursive and does not process more than 5 URLs, the conditions 1 and 3 are never met.

You can change that by using

```
builder.setBolt("status", new MemoryStatusUpdater())
```

instead. This way new URLs will be processed continuously. Alternatively, you can add

```
warcbolt.withSyncPolicy(new CountSyncPolicy(1));
```

to your code so that the synchronization is triggered after every tuple. In practice, you wouldn't need to do that on a real crawl where URLs are coming constantly.

Now the weird thing is that regardless of whether the sync is triggered by condition 1 or 2, I can't see any change to the file at all and it remains at 0 bytes. This is not the case with version 1.8

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-crawler-warc</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

so it could be due to a change in the code after that.

I know that some users have been relying on FileTimeSizeRotationPolicy, which can trigger condition 3 above based on time.

Feel free to open an issue on Github, I'll have a closer look at it (when I am back next month).

**EDIT**: there was a bug with the compression of the entries which has now been fixed and will be part of the next SC release.

See comments on the [issue](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/issues/596) kindly posted by the OP.

Comment: Thank you so much, Julien for having a look at this - much appreciated. I am by no means an expert on Storm, but I installed Storm 1.2.1 and tried to run it with 0.8 of StormCrawler and it also failed for me. Anyways I will open an issue as suggested.